# Invalid Credentials Prompt Missing on Woocommerce My Account Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have been trying to resolve an issue for the last week but I haven't been able to. When incorrect credentials are provided by a user on Woocommerce My Account page (Login Try with incorrect username and password) on my site, the page re-loads but there is no prompt for the user that he/she has entered an incorrect username or password. I tried using hooks `woocommerce_process_login_errors` and `login_errors` but the issue still stays the same. I have tried to use these hooks as follows:

```
add_filter('login_errors', 'filter_login_errors', 10, 1);   
function filter_login_errors( $error ) {
    if (empty($error)) return $error;
    
    $warning = '<br />Invalid username or password.';
    return $error .= $warning;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_process_login_errors', 'myplugin_login_errors',10,3);
function myplugin_login_errors($validation_error, $post_username, $post_password){
        
    wc_add_notice( "Invalid username or password", 'error' );
    return $validation_error;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For me both hooks work. It could be due to other functions overriding yours or the theme you are using. If you switch to a default theme does it work?

Comment: @VincenzoDiGaetano looks like there are some conflicts which are preventing these hooks to work as you said. I think I need to write some custom workaround.